# Composer Participants in Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

What is the role of Participants in Composer with an issued ID in Fabric?
When I issue a Business Network Card for a Composer Participant and connect to the Network how is this related to the Fabric architecture? Is the Participant an Application in Fabric or can he communicate over an Application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a typical example/sample Fabric - When you Issue an ID (and create a Business Network Card) you are issuing an ID from the Fabric-CA.

With Composer, every connection you make to the Fabric uses a Business Network Card (and ID).  This applies to every CLI command, every playground session, the REST API and your own applications.

Composer Concepts are [described here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/introduction/key-concepts.html).